# recvfrom() return values in Stop-and-Wait UDP?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am trying to implement a `Stop-and-Wait UDP` client-server socket program in C. As known, there are basically **three possible scenarios** for `Stop-and-Wait` flow control. i.e., After transmitting a packet,

1. the sender receives a correct `ACK` and thus starts transmitting the next packet;
2. the sender receives an incorrect `ACK` and thus retransmits this packet;
3. the sender receives no `ACK` within a `TIMEOUT` and thus retransmits this packet.

My idea is to differentiate these three scenarios with the return value of `recvfrom()` on the sender side.

- For scenario 1&2: `recvfrom()` just returns the length of the received `ACK`. Since in my implementation the incorrect `ACK` is of the same length of the correct one, so I will have to go deeper and check the contents of the `ACK`. It's not a big deal. I know how to do.
- Problems come when I am trying to recognize scenario 3 where no `ACK` is received. What confuses me is that my `recvfrom()` is within a while loop, so the `recvfrom()` will be called constantly. **What will it return when the receiver is not actually sending the sender `ACK`? Is it 0 or 1?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a receive timeout due to setting `SO_RCVTIMEO,` `recvfrom()` (and friends) will return -1 with `errno` set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`

[man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom): "EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK: The socket is marked nonblocking and the receive operation would block, or a receive timeout had been set and the timeout expired before data was received."

Comment: According to man page, the function will fail only if its called on NON_BLOCKING fd and no data is available to read.
[EAGAIN] or [EWOULDBLOCK]

The socket's file descriptor is marked O_NONBLOCK and no data is waiting to be received; or MSG_OOB is set and no out-of-band data is available and either the socket's file descriptor is marked O_NONBLOCK or the socket does not support blocking to await out-of-band data.

Comment: Not according to the man page cited above, or the wording for `SO_RCVTIMEO` [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsockopt.html).

Comment: ok. you are correct. I got confused with another man page script. Thanks for clarification.